# In Powershell -- Export object to textfile in custom format

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Since, i am a beginner, i 've no much hands-on to the powershell programming.Although
i had a script developed to insert data from an array to the csv file as follows:

```
#Following is the array
$InventoryReport = New-Object -TypeName PSobject -Property @{
                        ComputerName = "1myComputerName"
                        DomainName = "2myComputerDomain"
                        Manufacturer = "3myComputerManufacturer"
}

#Now to export the data to csv, i am using following:
$InventoryReport |Select-Object -Property ComputerName, DomainName, Manufacturer | Export-Csv -Path "c:\abc.csv" -NoTypeInformation -ErrorAction Stop

#This works fine
```

and the output of above is :

> "ComputerName","DomainName","Manufacturer"
>   "1myComputerName","2myComputerDomain","3myComputerManufacturer"

....
**Now, i don't want this , i want the ouput to appear in columnar fashion i.e.**

```
"ComputerName","1myComputerName"
"DomainName","2myComputerDomain"
"Manufacturer","3myComputerManufacturer"
```

What code changes should be done to achieve this. ?

Answer (score 1):

Either you want CSV, which you already have, or you want a custom txt-file. If you want the latter, try this:

```
$comp = gwmi win32_computersystem

@"
"ComputerName","$($comp.Name)"
"DomainName","$($comp.Domain)"
"Manufacturer","$($comp.Manufacturer)"
"@ | Out-File test.txt
```

sample of test.txt output below. I've got a non-domain, custom built pc, so don't worry about the values.

```
"ComputerName","GRAIMER-PC"
"DomainName","WORKGROUP"
"Manufacturer","System manufacturer"
```

**EDIT** I suggest you learn what CSV is. Remember that CSV is not a fileformat, it's a formatting-style used in a normal textfile. The `.csv` extension is just cosmetic to let people know that the textfile uses the csv-style. Check out [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx)

> In the CSV file, **each object is represented by a comma-separated list
>   of the property values of the object**. The property values are
>   converted to strings (by using the ToString() method of the object),
>   so they are generally represented by the name of the property value.
>   Export-CSV does not export the methods of the object.
>
> The format of an exported file is as follows:
>
> -- The first line of the CSV file contains the string '#TYPE ' followed by the fully qualified name of the object, such as #TYPE
>   System.Diagnostics.Process. To suppress this line, use the
>   NoTypeInformation parameter.
>
> -- The **next line of the CSV file represents the column headers**. It contains a comma-separated list of the names of all the properties of
>   the first object.
>
> -- **Additional lines of the file consist of comma-separated lists of the property values of each object.**

Comment: Hi Graimer,
This solution looks, very staright forward.
but i am looking for and export-csv to be used for genrating the csv file in a columnar fashion.

Comment: @Graimer has provided you with exactly what you asked for. It's name/value pairs, one per line, separated by commas, with quotes around the text.

Comment: @Ambrish I'm not trying to be rude, BUT YOU'RE NOT LISTENING. CSV's format is one row per object with properties/columns seperated by a delimiter (comma is default). I've added some links and quotes from wikipedia and technet's documentation for `export-csv`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
$InventoryReport | Format-List ComputerName, DomainName, Manufacturer `
  | Out-String -Stream `
  | ? { $_ -ne '' } `
  | % { $_ -replace '\s+:\s+', '","' -replace '(^|$)', '"' }
```